# image cache in the gallery

Tags: android

It is possible to save an image in an application cache, and these same images being used in a gallery. These images must be downloaded from the internet. Could give me an explanation of how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,,

Use `NetworkImageService` which will fetch image remotly from server.

```
class NetworkImageService {

public Image getImage(name) { ... }

}
```

Just make another subclass.

```
 class CachedNetworkImageService extends NetworkImageService {

Cache cache = new Cache();

public Image getImage(name) { ... 
      Image img = cache.get(name);
      if( img == null ) {
             img = super.getImage(name);
             cache.put( name, img );
      }
      return img.
}
}
```

Read about Hashmap. It will work...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the LruCache for that. Read the docu [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html).